issue in running docker compose up
I have been trying to run :
docker compose up -d

And getting below error :-
error during connect: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2FdockerDesktopLinuxEngine/v1.46/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.config-ha
sh%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.project%3Dodpt-orchestrator%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": open //./pipe/dockerDesktopLinuxEngine: The system cannot find the file specified.

I tried to run via administrator in powershell that didnt help. In one of the articles I read that docker service needs to be started, so I tried below :
net start com.docker.service

This also didnt help.
Some additional things :-
my docker version is :
Client:
Version:           27.2.0
API version:       1.47
Go version:        go1.21.13
Git commit:        3ab4256
Built:             Tue Aug 27 14:17:17 2024
OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
Context:           desktop-linux
and wsl -l -v is :-
NAME            STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu-18.04    Running         1
 Ubuntu-24.04    Stopped         1

